# ASA 5510 8.4 Nat & Portforwarding

Tags: nat, port-forwarding, cisco-asa

So I'm trying to forward an internal service on a internal server to the external interface on the same port on the outside interface of our ASA.

I been searching for a solution for days and found nothing.

Here are the relevant parts of my config:

```
: Saved
:
ASA Version 8.4(2)
!
object service TCP-WebServer-8080
 service tcp source eq 8080
object network WebServer_Object_10.1.10.7
 host 10.1.10.7
object network obj-10.1.100.0
 subnet 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0
!
access-list outsidein extended permit ip object-group OUTSIDE object-group INSIDE
access-list insideout extended permit ip object-group INSIDE object-group OUTSIDE
access-list webserveraccess extended permit tcp any object WebServer_Object_10.1.10.7 eq 8080
!
nat (inside,outside) source dynamic obj-10.1.10.0 interface
!
access-group webserveraccess in interface outside
access-group insideout in interface inside
!
object network WebServer_Object_10.1.10.7
 nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp 8080 8080
```

Here's the packet tracer output:

```
Phase: 1
Type: ROUTE-LOOKUP
Subtype: input
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
in   1.2.3.4   255.255.255.255 identity

Phase: 2
Type: ACCESS-LIST
Subtype:
Result: DROP
Config:
Implicit Rule
Additional Information:

Result:
input-interface: outside
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
output-interface: NP Identity Ifc
output-status: up
output-line-status: up
Action: drop
Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule
```

So it looks like it's being dropped by an ACL, but it looks right to me. Can I have some guidance as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my (Dynamic PAT) overrides my Static PAT (Port Forward) configuration

nat (inside,outside) source dynamic obj-10.1.10.0 interface

Removed with

no nat (inside,outside) source dynamic obj-10.1.10.0 interface

And then add it as

nat (inside,outside) after-auto source dynamic obj-10.1.10.0 interface

Then it worked.